# vscode can't find python with poetry and wsl

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I want to use a python interperter "created" by poetry in vscode trough WSL, but the right python version doesn't show up in vscode.

I run the following commmands in a WSL terminal:

```
$ poetry shell
Spawning shell within /home/kwint/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/metal-hub-python-py3.7
$ code .
```

the only interperters found in vscode are the ones in `/usr/`. I have tried manually inputting the path to the virtualenv but no luck. This is the path `which python` returns: `/home/kwint/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/metal-hub-python-py3.7/bin/python`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either manually specify `"python.pythonPath"` to `/home/kwint/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/metal-hub-python-py3.7/bin/python` or try setting `"python.venvPath"` to `/home/kwint/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs` and that should detect all virtual environments created by Poetry.

Also, please  the [feature request to detect Poetry virtual environments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8372) if you would like to see official support.

Answer (score 0):

Add `poetry.toml` to your project root with content:

```
[virtualenvs]
create = true
in-project = true
```

This will create the virtual environment in your project root instead of `~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs` (mac):

```
$ poetry shell
```

Install the dependencies:

```
$ poetry install
```

Now, selecting the kernel, you will find your poetry virtual environment in the project root as `.venv`.

Answer (score 0):

after run `poetry install` you need to select the interpreter, so type ctrl + shift + p on your visual studio code, then select the interpreter that matches your recently created project.

[image]